# Indexing thousands of records into Elasticsearch using Index API synchronous is right approach?

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I am trying to index more than 7000 records into elasticsearch. I will pick all those records from JSonarray based on it's length i will loop through the array and i will index records one by one into elasticsearch using Indexrequest API. Since i am new to Elastisearch i wanted to confirm is this right approach. I have given my code below.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < odsData.size(); i++) {
                IndexRequest request = new IndexRequest(ConstantsHelper.INDEX_NAME + strDate);
                request.id();
                String jsonString = odsData.get(i).toString();
                request.source(jsonString, XContentType.JSON);
                IndexResponse indexResponse = client.index(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
            }
```

In this a right approach? Also i wanted to check No of records in array and no of records indexed in the Elasticsearch are matching once indexing gets completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that should work fine, but it will be a slow process. There is also a bulk indexing API that you can use to index multiple documents at once which is very fast. [Link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-document-bulk.html)

Comment: How many records should i kept in a single bulk request? Because my data size will be dynamic, because somedays like 7000 records and someday 12000? Is there any limit

Comment: I have done it using 10000 document at once and it works fine. But in my opinion 1000 should be a good number. I also depends on the size of data that you are indexing.

Comment: So for 10000 documents i should be hitting BulkResponse bulkResponse 10 times am i right?

Comment: Yes, I actually have not used the Java API, I have done it using Python, but it should work the same.

Comment: Ok, Let me try on this and keep you posted

Comment: Hey @sanjaym can you accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks you very much